# Running Detox - what are the perquisites from the CI framework?

Tags: react-native, detox

I have a React-Native app.
I want to run Detox tests when a PR is being created.
I need the CI Framework to be able to run IOS Simulator and Android Emulator.

Currently using BitBucket but Im asking in general - What I should verify in my CI framework (BitBucket, GitLab, Github, etc) in order to make sure it can run Detox?

Answer (score 0):

Detox has a [guide](https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/guide/running-on-ci) for that (although it's not very updated).

Generally, you just need to execute the `detox build` and `detox test` commands from you CI, with the desired configuration. For that, you need to make sure you have the required environment installed (homebrew, [applesimutils](https://github.com/wix/AppleSimulatorUtils), [detox-cli](https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/api/detox-cli/#detox-command-line-tools-detox-cli), nodejs).